Slf4j logging an error from exec-maven-plugin
I noticed this in my Maven build logs
[ERROR] org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo - SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider]
What does it mean and why is this logged as an error?
Using exec-maven-plugin v3.4.1
